# Virtualbox alert on screen changes

Tags: linux, virtualbox, awesome-wm, alert

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux + awesome. Inside it I use virtualbox with ms windows.
Most time I spend in Linux, however I constantly need to monitor if something new happens in the guest system.

Is there any way to make virtualbox alerting about any changes on guest screen (clock is disabled, therefore only new mail or instant message may change the screen)?

PS. Unfortunately I can't to move mail and instant messages from windows due to specific clients for only internal network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to make VB alert you about screen change.

But you can try to make Windows in VB send you some kind of alerts trough VB-only isolated network if certain action happens (new mail arrives for example). Or trough IM client, or any other way that is easy to script.

This will require both some research and scripting. (It would be easier with two Linuxes...) The hardest part will be to inform already running script that action happened or run it when action happens.

Comment: I have some ideas how to implement it with two linuxes, unfortunately I have to use Windows, which is magic black box for me. I just thought there is some already existing solution. Hope somebody else will suggest some solution without deep research. Otherwise bounty is yours. =)